# CORS error while using SendGrid stating origin been blocked by CORS policy. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, django-rest-framework, cors, sendgrid

**BE Deployed:** On Heroku (DRF project)
**FE Deployed:** On Netlify (React project)

I have integrated SendGrid into my project. It is working fine on the local machine but throwing a CORS error after deployment on Heroku. It is not allowing me to log in at all.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at `https://<something>.herokuapp.com/auth/login/`
from origin `https://<something>.netlify.app` has been blocked by the CORS policy, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

To integrate SendGrid, I am using the following packages:

```
django-sendgrid-v5==1.2.2
sendgrid==6.10.0
```

I have set up all the required environment variables in Heroku's **Settings > Config Vars**:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'something'
EMAIL_HOST = 'something'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'something'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'something'
EMAIL_PORT = 'something'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = 'something'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'something'
EMAIL_FROM = 'something'
```

I have tried all possible solutions as per my knowledge. Since it is working on the local machine but not on Heroku, I added the free add-on called **Twilio SendGrid** and set up all the required parameters in the **Heroku app > Settings > Config Vars**.

But nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

your app at https://.herokuapp.com/auth/login/ needs to allow requests from https://.netlify.app

you can set following response header in your code at https://.herokuapp.com

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =  "*"
```

notes : this will allow incoming requests from all domains. its fine for testing but should change * to expected domain(s) before production use.